# COUNT Changes with Join on another Table MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count

I have the following Database Structure

```
Table Employee:

Name     ENr    
Name 1   1
Name 2   2
Name 3   3
...

Table Travel:

Employee  Costs
Name 1    8000
Name 1    56000
Name 2    800
```

and so on.

Now I want to Select The Name of the employees, the Count of the Travels and the Average Costs, as well as the ENr

Thats my SQL Select so far:

```
SELECT   employee,  COUNT(travel.employee), AVG(costs) FROM  travel  GROUP BY employee
```

However, as soon as I try to connect with the employee Table to add the ENr, my count is simply wrong. 
I tried to connect with simple:

```
SELECT ENr, Employee.. FROM travel, employee
```

And also with an INNER JOIN.

Hope somebody could help me out :)

Comment: @B001 - MySQL is a database and SQL is a standard. Stop mixing

Comment: Stop fighting, this poor Nicole W. is trying to have a solution to her problem not to be harassed with notifications...

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I will not tag SQL again, I'm new here :)

Comment: @NicoleW. You can use sql if you want, it does not bother in any way that it is a norm. The most important thing is to inform the database, what you have done so you are not wrong ^^

Comment: @CaiusJard It says "use that DBMS's tag instead."

Comment: yeah,but only if it's about db specific features.. (your quote is out of context - read the whole sentence that you only quoted the end of). Queries of the ilk `SELECT * FROM person WHERE name = 'smith'` isn't exactly leaning on a db specific feature..

Comment: @NicoleW. you should tag with sql if your query contains only ansi standard sql (yours does). Plenty of folks who've never used mysql in their life can still answer your question because it onoly uses standard sql, but if they search on [sql] they'll never find your question if it's not tagged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

You need `JOIN` conditions:

```
SELECT e.name, e.eNR, COUNT(*), AVG(t.costs)
FROM employee e JOIN
     travel t
     ON e.name = t.name
GROUP BY e.name, e.eNR;
```

Additional comments:

- When you have more than one table in a query, use table aliases and qualified column names.
- Include all non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`.
- `name` is a lousy foreign key.  Usually, you want foreign keys to be unique (names may not be unique).  And numbers are more efficient for indexing purposes.

Comment: Thank you so much! You helped me out a lot